# Find change in gross profit after price change

Tags: cost, profits, price

How do you solve this question?

> A company has 3 products. They contribute to 30%, 30% and 40% of sales
>   respectively.
>
> They have profit margins of 15%, 30%, and 50% respectively.
>
> If the client raises prices by 10% for Product A (assuming costs
>   remain constant), what is the change in the company's total gross
>   profit?

Is sales the same as total revenue (TR) or is it the same as profit ($\pi = TR - TC$)?

If it's the same as total revenue, I know that product A contributes 30% to the total sales, i.e.

$$
0.3 \cdot TR = TR_A
$$

Profit margin is given as $\tfrac{TR - TC}{TR}$, and if the profit margin of profit A is 10% then
$$
\frac{1.1 \cdot TR - TC}{1.1 \cdot TR} = 1 - \frac{TC}{1.1 \cdot TR}
$$

If the client raises prices by 10% for product A, the total revenue (TR) is now
$$
TR' = 1.1 \cdot P \cdot Q = 1.1 \cdot TR
$$

But how do i summarize? How can I conclude what the change in company's total gross profit is?

Comment: Are you assuming that the demand for products is fairly inelastic. That is number of units sold for each product will be same even after price increase ?

Comment: All else (costs, units of each product sold and costs of each product ) constant, the profit of company will increase by 5.78%.

Comment: Yes everything is held constant. How did you calculate this?

Comment: Just take any example. Calculate the profits and the percentage change.

Comment: I get a result of 12%. Can you elaborate how you did?